# Formal Properties of Coherence relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, coherence

Suppose that two particles a and b are in a coherent state.

Is the coherence relation between a and b satisfy all of the following?

(1) Irreflexive: a and b are distinct particles (although they might be 'identical' in the sense that they are of the same type).

(2) Symmetric: if a is coherent with b, b is coherent with a.

(3) Transitivity: if a is coherent with b, b with c, then a is coherent with c.

In particular, I wonder if (1) holds for any case, and if it does or doesn't why that is the case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by a particle being in a coherent state? Coherent states are usually states of bosonic modes with many particles at once.

Comment: the word "coherent" has a broad meaning of having some definite phase relationship between two (or more) objects, but it can have specific meanings in different contexts. so could you elaborate your question (e.g. what kind of experiment are you thinking about)?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccurate question. I was referring to, say, a canonical coherent state involving (presumably) two photons. Part of my question is whether there is a coherent state involving only one photon. If not, then what I called the coherence relation would be irreflexive --- at least that's how I used the term in the question.

Comment: @IamAStudent. Again, I had in mind a canonical coherent state involving photons. Now, when you said  ""coherent" has a broad meaning of having some definite phase relationship between two (or more) objects", I wonder what formal feature of the relation demands that it has to do with some relationship between more than two objects, instead of one and the same object. I'm curious if it does not make sense to say that a particle stands in that relation with *itself* (at the same moment), and if it doesn't, why exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks, based on the comments above.

1. > Part of my question is whether there is a coherent state involving only one photon.

   A coherent state (occasionally called Glauber state), by definition, has a non-zero (albeit small) amplitude in arbitrarily large photon-number state. A coherent state with an average photon number of one is distinct from a single photon Fock state.
2. > If not, then what I called the coherence relation would be irreflexive --- at least that's how I used the term in the question.

   I assume irreflexivity in your context means a quantum state cannot be "in coherence relation" to itself. I really can't answer this question clearly, because the [degree of coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_coherence) in quantum optics (developed by Roy Glauber) is about the statistical properties of light. Experimentally, you prepare some particular quantum state of light, detect photons from it at particular spacetime points, and collect statistics on correlations between photons. So there are many iterations, but they all involve the same state of light (ideally). So I am not sure if your question about defining coherence relation as a relation between two distinct quantum states is well-proposed. Naively, you associate the quality of coherence with observing some interference fringes, and trivially, a quantum state does not interfere with orthogonal states (zero overlap in Hilbert space).